# Designing API client with lots of paramaters in Python

Tags: python, oop, rest, design-patterns

I'm building a client in Python for a popular RESTful API and I'm trying to figure out the best way to build my methods for endpoints which have lots of optional values.

Let me explain.

First, I have a method that can translate named arguments to the appropriate json representation.

```
def map_kwargs_to_payload(self, **kwargs):
    payload = {}
    for key in kwargs:
        payload[key] = kwargs[key]

    return payload
```

This allows me to create function signatures that look like so:

```
def some_rest_method(**kwargs):
    payload = map_kwargs_to_payload(**kwargs)
    self.transmit('PUT', '/endpoint', payload)
```

This works great - it saves me from having to do something like below when there are a lot of options the user could pass to the method.

```
def some_rest_method(setting_1=None, setting_2=None, setting_3=None, etc...):
```

But where it fails is when the request body wants something like below, where the endpoints have several optional body paramaters:

```
{
  "setting_1" : foo,
  "setting_2" : foo,
  "setting_3" : [{
               "IsEnabled" : 1,
               "Type" : x
         }, {
               "IsEnabled" : 1,
               "Type" : x
         }
  ]
}
```

My mapper doesn't support nesting arrays such as the above request requires.

So how should I go about solving this? Should I just make the user pass in a dict representation of the body? Is there some other better way to keep my method signatures of reasonable length whilst doing as much as possible for the end user?

Comment: `kwargs` is already a dict.  `def map_kwargs_to_payload(self, **kwargs): return kwargs`?  Or maybe even `dict(k1=v1, k2=v2)`?

Comment: So how would the user pass to the method setting_3 with an array of options?

Comment: Arguments to `dict()` can be any Python object.  Isn't `dict(setting_3=[dict(Type=x, IsEnabled=1), ...])` OK?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem here is that you are not actually modeling with objects those API concepts, so you can't delegate responsibilities to them. When I'm faced with this kind of situations I create two models: a low-level OO representation of the API and a high-level OO model for my domain. In this way all the concepts in the application are represented (the API and the domain) and thus I can delegate to them as I see it fits. There are a couple of similar questions here where I explained this in detail:

[Mapping/decoupling remote data with local objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311654/mapping-decoupling-remote-data-with-local-objects/14322486)

[Most suitable design pattern for an app that makes various requests from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878329/most-suitable-design-pattern-for-an-app-that-makes-various-requests-from-a-serve/13878512)

HTH